# How can I reference js file from node_modules folder in page head in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have added package [onesignal-emoji-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-emoji-picker) to my nuxt.js vue project and I want to reference css and js files in my pages without copying them to static folder. css is included with ease in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
css: ['~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/css/emoji.css']
```

but I could not manage to reference js files, `head.script` section seems to work only for external resources:

```
script: [
  {
    src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  },
  {
    src: '~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/config.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  },
  {
    src: '~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/util.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  },
  {
    src: '~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/jquery.emojiarea.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  },
  {
    src: '~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/emoji-picker.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  }
]
```

[image]
[image]

It seems to me that I should somehow tell webpack to include this files on build and reference them appropriately? How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: hey @Andrey any answer? I'm also wondering the same...

Comment: @SabaAhang nope ((

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66633626/8816585) works perfectly (you can remove the mode if you want to have it isomorphic).

Answer (score 6):

In `nuxt.config.js`, simply use the `plugins` key for including any internal scripts:

```js
plugins: [
    { src: "~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/config.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/util.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/jquery.emojiarea.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/js/emoji-picker.js", mode: "client" }
]
```

Note the **`mode: "client"`** option which means the files will only be run on the client, preventing issues on the server if the library is not compatible with server-side-rendering. You may want to remove the flag in other cases.

Comment: i am using nuxt3, and this doesn't work. unfortunately I don't know the answer yet :")

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `./server/index.js` and add the express static route just before this line `app.use(nuxt.render)`.

The final `start()` function should be like this

```
async function start () {
  ...

  app.use("/node_modules", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../node_modules')))
  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  ....
}
```

After this change you can add `node_modules` libraries inside the vue page header.

```
export default {
    head:{
        script: [
            { src: "/node_modules/three/build/three.min.js", type: 'text/javascript', charset: 'utf-8'}
        ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use nodes path library. I think it's one of the nuxt dependency so it should be already installed, if not just install it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/path

Then import at the top of your `nuxt.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')

....

css: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/css/emoji.css')]
```

same thing with scripts